# Changing the hard coded path to my desirable path

Tags: batch-file

I need to change the path that is defined in the file i.e `duster.properties` with my desired path location.

File i.e `duster.properties` contents :-

```
 com.test.import.uploadDirectory=C:\\progra~2\\Test\\Demo\\jboss7\\standalone\\uploads
 com.test.import.maxFilesUploadNumber=10

com.test.etl.pluginsRootDirectory=C:\\progra~2\\Test\\Demo\\jboss7\\standalone\\cloverETL\
\plugins
 com.test.etl.templatesDirectory=C:\\progra~2\\Test\\Demo\\jboss7\\standalone\\etl
 com.test.db.user=postgres
 com.test.db.pass=password
 com.test.addressdoctor.customerID=149374
 com.test.addressdoctor.password=apr2511
 com.test.addressdoctor.maxi.customerID=146890
```

As you could see in the duster.properties the location is hard coded

```
   C:\\progra~2\\Test\\Demo\\jboss7\\standalone\\uploads
```

But i can locate my jboss7 location anywhere in the system i.e C drive or D drive.

I'm able to search the location of jboss7 and set the path of it into the variable name i.e 'folderLocation' using the following code.

```
 @echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir "c:\jboss7" /b /s /ad ') do if /i "%%~nxa"=="jboss7" set
"folderLocation=%%a"

if not defined folderLocation for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir "d:\jboss7" /b /s /ad ')
do if /i "%%~nxa"=="jboss7" set "folderLocation=%%a"
echo "%folderLocation%"
pause
```

Now what i want is to edit the file and set the variable i.e folderLocation to the path
  or in simple words find and replace the path.
     . e.g:-

```
'folderLocation'\\standalone\\uploads
```

and like wise in every path of duster.properties.
Is it possible in batch scripting ? Actually i don't have good knowledge in batch scripting.

Any help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This works with your sample data and uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
@echo off
set "newpath=d:\\stuff\\and\\widgets"
type "duster.properties" | repl "(Directory=).*(\\\\standalone\\\\)" "$1%newpath%$2" >"duster.properties.tmp"
move "duster.properties.tmp" "duster.properties"
```

Comment: thanx . Do i have to include repl.bat script into my script?
or any other solution of it ?

Comment: Actually duster.properties file is in the location of C:\\progra~2\\Test\\Demo\\jboss7\\standalone\\uploads and likewise i have few more files that are exiting in the different folder locations to be edited.

Comment: You put repl.bat on your path and it can be used in many other tasks - or put it in the same folder with the batch file I supplied above.

Comment: ya thanx . Now i have putted both the batch file i.e repl.bat and myfile.bat in the same folder . myfile.bat file consists of the above your code with my code of finding folder.Just double clicked to myfile.bat and getting an error  "C:\Users\LilBird\Desktop\repl.bat(1, 6) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Conditional compilation is turned off"

Comment: I think my approach is not very clear to you . Shall i raise another question with all the codes and process that i have tried?

Comment: Edit my post if you can, and add the code you are using, below my code.  We need to see how you have modified it.  Or edit your question an d add it at the bottom.

Comment: So kind of you . 
Foxidrive , i just noticed few more things into the duster.properties file that path is appended with double slash.
like C:\\progra~

I have a rasied a new ques. Kindly check it and do needful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913438/changing-the-path-location-of-a-file-to-the-desired-path

Answer (score -1):

use parent path method
File currentPath = new File(dir.getParent())
String currentFolder= currentPath.getName().toString()